# Create a rectangle filled with text

Tags: r, ggplot2, blogdown

I'd like to create a filled rectangle in R, with white text centered in the middle, and export it to png. I know the `rect()` function can probably do this, but every example I've seen the rectangle is printed on a plot. Is there a way to do this without the plot?

For reference, I'm building a `blogdown()` site and trying to create a square that looks pretty much identical to those in the [Hugrid](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugrid/) theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear from your question what exactly the sticking point is. Do you need to generate the rectangles from R (instead of, say, manually in Illustrator)? And no plot window must be shown?

All of this can be achieved. I prefer to draw with ggplot2, and the specific geoms you'd need here are `geom_tile()` for the rectangles and `geom_text()` for the text. And you can save to png without generating a plot by using `ggsave()`.

```
rects <- data.frame(x = 1:4,
                    colors = c("red", "green", "blue", "magenta"),
                    text = paste("text", 1:4))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(rects, aes(x, y = 0, fill = colors, label = text)) +
  geom_tile(width = .9, height = .9) + # make square tiles
  geom_text(color = "white") + # add white text in the middle
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "none") + # color the tiles with the colors in the data frame
  coord_fixed() + # make sure tiles are square
  theme_void() # remove any axis markings

ggsave("test.png", p, width = 4.5, height = 1.5)
```

[image]

I made four rectangles in this example. If you need only one you can just make an input data frame with only one row.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `geom_rect()` to create rectangles and `geom_text()` to paste text into them. Modifying rectangle look (color, line size or type) in `ggplot2` is easy. All you have to do is to remove default `ggplot2` look with `theme_classsic()` and `element_blank()`.

```
# Generate dummy dataset
foo <- data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 2, y1 = 1, y2 = 2,
                  text = paste(letters[1:3], letters[1:3], collapse = "\n"))

# Plot rectangle with text
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(foo) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = y1, ymax = y2),
              color = "black", size = 2, fill = "lightblue") +
    geom_text(aes(x = x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2, y = y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2,
                  label = text),
              size = 20) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line  = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text  = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: There’s `theme_void()` for such cases. No need to empty the theme manually.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lightweight solution,

```
rects <- data.frame(fill = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Pastel1"),
                    colour = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Set1"),
                    label = paste("text", 1:5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(gridExtra)
gl <- mapply(function(f,l,c) grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=f, col="white",lwd=2)),
                                      textGrob(l, gp=gpar(col=c))),
             f = rects$fill, l = rects$label, c = rects$colour,
             SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

grid.arrange(grobs=gl)
```

[image]